# Using object SomeController extends Controller in Play framework 2.5 instead

Tags: scala, model-view-controller, playframework, playframework-2.0

We're in the progress of upgrading to play 2.5.5 from play 2.4.x. We have a 
pretty large amount of controllers that are objects, like so:

```
object TranslationsController extends Controller { ... }
```

However, since switching to 2.5, we now get hundreds of errors like this 
(it's a pretty huge project):

```
type TranslationsController is not a member of package controllers
```

Is there a way to still allow some/most our Controllers to be object and 
not class? I realize this has everything to do with dependency injection. 
But a pretty large percentage of the controllers, *has* no dependencies.

Of course, we could rewrite it like so just to make it compile:

```
class TranslationsController @Inject () extends Controller { ... }
```

but that's really pointless?? An immutable class/object that takes no 
parameters, *should* be an object. It's like `case class None()` vs `case 
object None`. Of course the latter should be the preferred one in every case.

The big deal here is that we can't just string replace object->class 
either, because we have a lot (~1000) of tests that assumes these 
controllers to be objects. To make it work with class, we would have to 
rewrite all those tests to first do a `val controller = 
new TranslationsController`, first, which is a lot of work (and tons of 
boilerplate).

I would really appreciate if there was some way to still use object. Is 
there some syntax for it in the `.routes` files, or is there an easy 
workaround? I mean, once there are dependencies to these controllers, we'll 
make them classes, but to do that to 100 controllers in one go without any 
benefit is pretty painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to keep those controllers if you tell Play to use the old routes generator. In your `build.sbt` put:

```
routesGenerator := StaticRoutesGenerator
```

and reload your project